# MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter from xml to java configuration Malfunctioning

Tags: java, jackson, resttemplate

I change my application from a xml-based configuration to a java-based configuration. In the java-based configuration, I get below error, which I don't get in the xml-based configuration. What I'm missing in the java configuration? Please assist.

The method throwing this error:

```
 response = restTemplate.exchange(uri.toUri(), HttpMethod.GET, entity, UserProfiles.class);
```

The error :

```
nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.mycompany.wsg.profile.model.v26.gen.ListItemDef: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('U-71155f93-8413-457c-a045-256dc6ab0a93@poims001.ucc2.ucc.stgsip.t-mobile.com')
```

Comment: Check that the response is a valid JSON and also your `UserProfile` class has default (no-argument) constructor.

Comment: The pojos are not the issue; since the same classes in the xml based configuration work fine. The only thing I did was changing the xml files into java. The codebase has not been touched; but yet the xml-based configuration works but the java is throwing this error. My instinct is that there's a java configuration I'm missing

Comment: I look like there's an issue deserializing list items. All the posting I've read sofar related to my issue is when deserializing a list. I try to deserialize a list as well

Answer (score 0):

The issue was definitely the java configuration. Here's how I resolve it:

```
public class SpringWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

  ....//unrelated configuration here

 @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate()
    {
        RestTemplate restTemplate =  new RestTemplate(httpClientFactory());

        restTemplate.setMessageConverters(getMessageConverters());

        return restTemplate;
    }


 @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(
      List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {

        converters.add(createXmlHttpMessageConverter());
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }

    private HttpMessageConverter<Object> createXmlHttpMessageConverter() {
        MarshallingHttpMessageConverter xmlConverter = 
          new MarshallingHttpMessageConverter(jaxb2Marshaller(), jaxb2Marshaller());

        return xmlConverter;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone else